# How to match Google, OpenLayers and shapefile data?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I've installed OpenLayers plugin and opened Google satellite layer in QGIS.

For a point in Beijing china, it's shown as 12961957,4852605 coordinate in blue status bar, and it should be 116.33710,39.83818 in longitude and latitude.

I also have some shapefile which are in lat & long coordinate for Beijing area. So how can I overlay the shapefile data on top of Google layer in correct position?

Anyone can help me or provide some hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the openlayers plugin, the **project** CRS must be in EPSG:3857, Web Mercator. That's the format the google tiles are delivered in.

It is no problem if your shapefile is in degrees. Set the CRS for that **layer** to EPSG:4326, and check on-the-fly-reprojection.

Comment: thanks andre. great. it's work. it's really work. amazing.

Comment: andre. would you mind to answer other few question? if i have shapefile in coordinate seconds.(longigute multiply 3600) how to match it with google layer ? and how to georeference a shapefile layer ?

Comment: sure. i know. but i can't find accepted button on this page.